# Incorrect report of "multiple definitions"

Tags: c++, linker, g++, ubuntu

I have been working on a cross-platform library in C++. I been compiling both in Windows (MinGW/msys) and Ubuntu (g++) and it compiles without any errors.

I just got the hand on a computer with Kubuntu. When I try to compile it there I get some errors saying that I have multiple definitions on some variables. Those variables are defined `extern` in a header file and defined in one cpp at one line.

```
./libAoTK.a(aotk_unix.o):/home/rickard/c++/AoTK/src/aotk_unix.cpp:16: multiple definition of `AoTK::disp'
./libAoTK.a(aotk_unix.o):/home/rickard/c++/AoTK/src/aotk_unix.cpp:12: first defined here
```

The code in [aotk_unix.cpp](https://github.com/r-englund/AoTK/blob/master/src/aotk_unix.cpp) has only one definition of `disp`, and on lines 12 and 16 there are no references to `disp`.

I do not understand why it fails to link, while the exact same code compiles fine on another *nix machine.

Comment: What are the gcc versions that success and fail?

Comment: Are you sure that the link is the same file as /home/richard/...../aotk_unix.cpp?

Comment: I just checked out the github repository and was able to build the tests successfully. Try a `make clean` and rebuild.

Comment: The problem was that i was missing the r-flag when creating the lib file so that the new o-files didnt overwrite the old ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out with the help of bdonlans comment. The problem was in my makefile when creating lib-archive. I used the command

```
ar -cvq
```

which did not overwrite exist files in the archive, when changing to

```
ar -cr
```

it links without any errors